# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio to jump up to the parent XML/XHTML node in XML code view?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xhtml, keyboard-shortcuts

Not too sure how to elaborate on this over what the title already states, but it would be super great if when I was hovering my carat on a node in the XML/XHTML source view, that I could press a key to jump up to the parent node.

If not in Visual Studio, is it in any addons like ReSharper or [can't remember the name of any others..!]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ReSharper you can navigate to "Containing Declaration" (default key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>, customize by changing `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoContainingDeclaration`). From the Visual Studio menu you can use ReSharper - Navigate - Containing Declaration. This works in XML, XHTML and C#.

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>Mikael</name>
  </person>
</persons>
```

If you're cursor is inside "Mikael", first command of "navigate to containing declaration" will take you to the "name", then the next one will move you up to "person" and after the third command you will end up in "persons".

Comment: The shortcut didn't work for me by default, but the function is there.

Comment: for me it was `Ctrl + [`